# Get Binary Placement

Tags: c#, math

I want to get the binary placement of a number.

`int val = 1 << 9;`
`Console.WriteLine(val); //512`

What I have now is the *opposite*. I have the value `512` and I want to get `9`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find a *binary logarithm*, you can do either explictly:

```
  int value = 512;

  ...

  int result = (int) (Math.Log(value) / Math.Log(2));
```

or by a simple loop:

```
  int value = 512;

  ... 

  int result = -1;

  for (; value != 0; value /= 2, ++result);

  Console.Write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> [Convert.ToInt32(String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx) lets you specify the base:

```
int output = Convert.ToInt32(input, 2);
```

Comment: May I know how this works? If I put 512 in input, it will return format exception.